# Disable buttons and prevent onclick handlers

Tags: javascript, button

I have a few buttons (`<a>` tag for historical reason of the project), and clicking on some of them should **disable other buttons' click handlers** (and the API requests they send).

This works, but not sure it's really natural.

**Is there a more standard JS way to handle this situation?**

```js
document.querySelector(".button1").onclick = (e) => {
   if (e.target.disabled)   // .disabled attribute is undefined by default
       return;
   console.log("button1 clicked");       
   fetch("/api/do_something");
};

document.querySelector(".button2").onclick = () => {
    console.log("button2 clicked");
    document.querySelector(".button1").disabled = true;
};
```

```css
.button { padding: 1em; background-color: #eee; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<a class="button button1">BUTTON1</a>

<a class="button button2">DISABLE BUTTON1</a>
```

Comment: Set `pointer-events: none` to the disabled buttons, that way you don't have to handle disabling in their event handlers. I'm not sure how this will work with keyboard navigation, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Teemu's comment:

```js
document.querySelector(".button1").onclick = (e) => {
   console.log("button1 clicked");       
   fetch("/api/do_something");
};
document.querySelector(".button2").onclick = () => {
    console.log("button2 clicked");
    document.querySelector(".button1").classList.add("disabled");
};
```

```css
.button { padding: 1em; background-color: #eee; cursor: pointer; }
.disabled { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<a class="button button1">BUTTON1</a>
<a class="button button2">DISABLE BUTTON1</a>
```